# Moving zip folder from one location to another using batch file

Tags: command-line, zip

I am working on the following scenario using batch file:

1. Copy certain sub folders from a folder and zip them into a new location.

   ```
   Zip %Output_Path%\ Apps_backup_%today%.zip \\%Server%\QlikViewfolder\Common\apps\*.qvw

   Zip %Output_Path%\_Gen_backup_%today%.zip \\%Server%\QlikViewfolder\Common\generators\*.*
   ```
2. zip all the zipped folders into one single folder

   ```
   Zip %Output_Path%\Daily_backup_%today%.zip %Output_Path%
   ```

   I am doing this step because I want all the files to be in a single folder. I did not find a way where I can copy specific sub folders from a folder and directly copy into one zip.
3. Move the zip folders to a new location.
4. Once moved, delete the previous day zip folder

I was able to do step 1 and 2. But not able to do step 3. Can you please advise on both step 3 and 4?

Comment: You already got all the information. Just use `move` (you got the path already where the file currently is) and delete the file afterwards using `del`.

Comment: I have used the following for step 3 and it works. move %Output_Path%\* \\New location\qlikview

Comment: Also, Step 4:  I am not able to delete ‘Daily_backup_5-14-2017’ after the Daily_backup_5-15-2017 zip is created. Can you please help me with the above-mentioned questions?

Comment: Does your target folder contain multiple older versions? If not just deleted everything in it. Otherwise, how do you get `%today%`, you might be able to use that method to get the date of the previous day.

Comment: I am using this variable: set today=%Month%-%Day%-%Year%
As you mentioned, I followed  deleting everything in it before the new folder is moved.
Step 2:
Zip %Output_Path%\Daily_backup_%today%.zip %Output_Path%
Step 3:
del \\New folder location\*.zip
Step4:
Move %Output_Path%\Daily_backup_%today%.zip to  \\New folder location

But I am stuck at writing the if else condition. I tried to use %ERRORLEVEL% but not able to get it working.  I want step three to 
 take place only if step 2 has completed successfully.

Comment: I am a new bee to this portal. Can you tell me how to mark your answer as correct?

Comment: It's not an answer (in the manner you could mark it). Check [the help portal](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) for some information about this. Essentially something has to show up as an answer for you to be able to mark it. This here would be a comment. I'll turn it into an answer shortly. You could also mark it as a helpful comment (little triangle if you hover a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already got the important pieces of information in place. You know the source and target filenames/directories and you have a variable `%today` which holds the current date.

To move the file you can either use `move` or some `copy` command. The important part is that you have the filename of your backup zip (`%Output_Path%\Daily_backup_%today%.zip`). If you use a copy command you will have to use `del` later on to remove the original file.

While you did explain in one of your comments that you're using the following code to assign the today variable, it doesn't actually explain a lot. The variables you use to build `%today` are not standard. So you already run some command to build them.

```
set today=%Month%-%Day%-%Year%
```

If you look at [How to get and display yesterday date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954359/how-to-get-and-display-yesterday-date) and [How to get yesterday's date in the batch file? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010670/how-to-get-yesterdays-date-in-batch-file) you will find that apparently there is no easy way to get yesterday's date in a batch. But you probably could use those solutions.

As your comment points out you're using the easier approach to delete "all" the old files (which should only be one) and then just move the new file.

What you now want to do is check whenever an operation was successful before you proceed. The value of `%errorlevel%` depends on the application you're dealing with. As an easy example, the following will return 0 which would indicate that there wasn't an error. Which kind of is true but probably not what you really want.

```
del C:\Temp\ThisFileDoesn'tExist.txt
echo %errorlevel%
```

A good question with information on this seems to be [check if the command was successful in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691494/check-if-command-was-successfull-in-a-batch-file).

I don't know which zip program you use and you will have to check the documentation for information on what values to expect etc. but meanwhile, instead of checking the return value, you could check whenever the file your expect exists. A good example for this is [How to check if a file exists from inside a batch file [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340350/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-inside-a-batch-file).

So what would be a possible solution?

1. Create your files as you have done before
2. Check if your backup file exists. This doesn't test if errors were encountered but at least you know something was written to a file that meets the name you want
3. Delete the old backups
4. Move the new backup file

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `xcopy` command. Set the start and end locations ex. as `xcopy "from" "to"`

```
@echo off
xcopy "download.zip" "D:\Games"
pause
```

if it doesn't work try `xcopy "" "D:\Games" download.zip`